# Keep only the last record if the value occurs continuously

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Keep only the last record if the values occurs continuously.

Input_df:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | 5 |
| 2022/01/03 | 4 |
| 2022/01/05 | 3 |
| 2022/01/06 | 3 |
| 2022/01/07 | 3 |
| 2022/01/08 | 4 |
| 2022/01/09 | 3 |

Output_df:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | 5 |
| 2022/01/03 | 4 |
| 2022/01/07 | 3 |
| 2022/01/08 | 4 |
| 2022/01/09 | 3 |

-- The value 3 repeats continuously for 3 dates, so we only keep the latest record out of the three continuous dates and if there is a different value transmitted in between the continuity breaks, so do not delete the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.diff` to create a flag and see is the column value is continous or not. See the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html).

Then drop line that are continous.

```
# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date" : ["2022/01/01", "2022/01/03", "2022/01/05", "2022/01/06", "2022/01/07", "2022/01/08", "2022/01/09"], 
    "Value" : [5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3]
})

# Create a flag 
df['Diff'] = df['Value'].diff(periods = -1).fillna(1)
df = df.loc[df['Diff'] != 0, :].drop('Diff', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with sql

```
 SELECT  distinct date, VALUE, 
  max(case 
  when value=lead(value) then 
 lead(date) else date end)
  Over (order by Null) from table;
```